# Adding groups to Jenkins without breaking migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

In a django project I'm writing I need one (for now, I may want more later) group that should be automatically setup when the server is run. I got this working by subclassing AppConfig but this seems to break migrations.

In thelibrary/**init**.py I have

```
default_app_config = 'thelibrary.apps.LibraryConfig'
```

I have the following located in thelibrary/apps.py

```
"""
    Handles initial configuration and site wide settings
"""

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User


from django.apps import AppConfig

"""
Group and permission configuration
"""

#Project Leaders

class LibraryConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'thelibrary'

    def ready(self):
        verbose_name = 'The Library'

        try:
            lead = Group.objects.get(name='lead')

        except: 
            Group.objects.create(name='lead')
```

This will setup the group 'lead' with no issues and it works perfectly as long as I have an existing database with no migrations needed. However when I try to create the initial database I have to comment out my group creation because there isn't a working database at this point.

What can I do to solve this issue? Is there a better way to have groups created when the project is first started?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of me, I should have just added another try, except.

```
class LibraryConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'thelibrary'

    def ready(self):
        verbose_name = 'The Library'

        try:
            lead = Group.objects.get(name='lead')

        except: 
            try:
                Group.objects.create(name='lead')
            except:
                print "Failed"
```